# How to toggle check all check-boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to toggle check-boxes? With javascript i can toggle check-boxes. but Jquery all toggle once.

```js
$("#check-all").click(function() {
  if ($("#check-all").checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.check').length; i++) {
      $(".check")[i].checked = false;
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.check').length; i++) {
      $(".check")[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
```

Comment: please explain in more detail what you want to achieve. it should be possible to understand that without having to go through your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$("#check-all").checked` is always `undefined` (which evaluates to `false` in your if else expression), since the jQuery wrapper `$("#check-all")` doesn't have a property named `checked`. To get the value of the element's `checked` property, you'll need to use the [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method. Get the current status of checked, and set it on all the other checkboxes using `.prop()` again:

```js
$("#check-all").click(function(e) {
  var checked = $(e.target).prop('checked');
  
  $(".check").prop('checked', checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Toggle using `.prop('checked', Boolean)`
- Use rather the `"change"` eventName
- Don't forget that you need to handle also the "All" checkbox when all the **group** ones are **checked / unchecked** by using `!$ckb.not(':checked').length`

Here's a better example that covers all the functionalities:

```js
const $all = $('#check-all');
const $ckb = $('.check');

$ckb.add($all).on('change', function() {
  if (this === $all[0]) {
    $ckb.prop('checked', this.checked);
  } else {
    $all.prop('checked', !$ckb.not(':checked').length);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="check-all"> All </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check"> 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check"> 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check"> 3</label>
```